# Deleting a node from javascript map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map defined as following and then I am adding all nodes to the map.

```
var map = {}
nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
  map[d.id] = i;
})
```

In the code snippet, pressing the `del` button deletes the node `GW` by calling the `del` function.
I am able to delete the entry from the nodes but not sure how to delete it from the map.

this is related to my [D3.js SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468873/d3-mousedown-event-deleting-the-wrong-node/51487414#51487414)

I am not using `var map1 = new Map();` otherwise, I think the following would have worked.

```
map.delete(d);
```

```html
<button id="del" onclick="del('GW')">del </button>
<script>

var nodes = [{
    id: "FH",
    x: 100,
    y: 110
  },
  {
    id: "TP",
    x: 200,
    y: 110
  },
  {
    id: "GW",
    x: 200,
    y: 110
  },
  {
    id: "DB",
    x: 100,
    y: 110
  }
]



var map = {}
nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
  map[d.id] = i;
})


function del(n) {
  var i = map[n];
  mousedownNode2(nodes[i], i);

}


function mousedownNode2(d, i) {
  nodes.splice(i, 1);
  console.log(map);
    console.log(nodes);

}

</script>
```

Comment: `delete map[d.id]` ?

Comment: Thanks, @KoshVery, `delete map[n];` worked a treat. Is there any specific name for `map ={}` ?  i think a map actually is `var map1 = new Map();`

Comment: `map = {}` is a shorthand for `map = new Object();` not for `new Map()`.

Comment: @nyi As mentioned above, you are using an object, not a map. You could use a real map, which is faster to iterate over. Also, you could use a D3 map: `var map = d3.map()`.