# Define nodes index by record id

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I'm trying to build a graph with d3 using this example: http://bl.ocks.org/jhb/5955887

Is the first time I try to use the d3 library and I'm trying to set the nodes with data coming from my database, this is an example of a node I want to build:

```
{
  index: 700,
  name: 'The person's name'
}
```

The data from the nodes came from a MySql table called Researchers, nothing more that a list of persons with their id and names:
[image]

As you can see, each Researcher has a related array that contains all the related researchers and this will be used to build the edges. Below is the code for set the graph edges and nodes:

```
const g_nodes = [];
const g_edges = [];
/*For each researcher, set the edges related to that researcher*/
this.state.nodes.forEach(n => {
  if (n.related.length > 0) {
    n.related.forEach(r => {
      g_edges.push({
        source: n.id,
        target: r.id,
        weight: r.RelatedResearcher.cs + r.RelatedResearcher.bc
      });
    })
  }
})
/*For each researcher set his/her node on the graph*/
this.state.nodes.forEach(n => {
  g_nodes.push({
    index: n.id,
    name: n.name
  });
})
console.log(g_edges);
console.log(g_nodes);
```

This picture is from the console.log(g_nodes) and work as expected:
[image]

The problem is that as soon as I put the edges and the nodes into the dataset object, the node's index change to the array position and the weight field appears on the node objects:

```
dataset.nodes = g_nodes;
dataset.edges = g_edges;
console.log(g_edges);
console.log(g_nodes);
```

[image]

When this happens, I get an error from d3:

```
TypeError: "r.source is undefined"
```

Then I look into the edges and the first edge receives undefined for the source and target:

```
0: Object { source: undefined, target: undefined, weight: 0.46782460000000003 }
```

Sorry about my, English and hope you can help. Thank you

Comment: D3v3 only supports links accessing source/target nodes by their position in the nodes array, not by a named property such as id (unless that id refers to index). But, if I understand your question properly, when d3 initializes the force layout it takes the each link's source/target properties and changes them from a numerical value to a the actual node object. Because of this you can easily use a property to set the link source and target manually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51390262/7106086

Comment: I'll see if that link helps and answer here, thank you very much

Comment: Perfect, it's done. Thank you