# Understanding why strings break this 3d.js force.graph code

Tags: d3.js

I am running this code in a jupyter notebook. First, I create this HTML element:

```
%%html
<div id="d3-example"></div>
<style>
.node {stroke: #fff; stroke-width: 1.5px;}
.link {stroke: #999; stroke-opacity: .6;}
</style>
```

Then I run this javascript:

```
%%javascript
// We load the d3.js library from the Web.
require.config({paths:
    {d3: "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min"}});
require(["d3"], function(d3) {
  // The code in this block is executed when the
  // d3.js library has been loaded.

  // First, we specify the size of the canvas
  // containing the visualization (size of the
  // <div> element).
  var width = 300, height = 300;

  // We create a color scale.
  var color = d3.scale.category10();

  // We create a force-directed dynamic graph layout.
  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(1)
    .size([width, height]);

  // In the <div> element, we create a <svg> graphic
  // that will contain our interactive visualization.
  var svg = d3.select("#d3-example").select("svg")
  if (svg.empty()) {
    svg = d3.select("#d3-example").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);
  }

  // We load the JSON file.
  d3.json("graph2.json", function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;
    // In this block, the file has been loaded
    // and the 'graph' object contains our graph.

    // We load the nodes and links in the
    // force-directed graph.
    force.nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

    // We create a <line> SVG element for each link
    // in the graph.
    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");



    // We create a <circle> SVG element for each node
    // in the graph, and we specify a few attributes.
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)  // radius
      .style("fill", function(d) {
         // The node color depends on the club.
         return color(d.club);
      })
      .call(force.drag);

    // The name of each node is the node number.
    node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    // We bind the positions of the SVG elements
    // to the positions of the dynamic force-directed
    // graph, at each time step.
    force.on("tick", function() {
      link.attr("x1", function(d){return d.source.x})
          .attr("y1", function(d){return d.source.y})
          .attr("x2", function(d){return d.target.x})
          .attr("y2", function(d){return d.target.y});

      node.attr("cx", function(d){return d.x})
          .attr("cy", function(d){return d.y});
    });
  });
});
```

And this is the content of the json file:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "name": 0,
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": 1,
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": 2,
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": 3,
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": 4,
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": 5,
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": 6,
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": 7,
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": 8,
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": 9,
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": 10,
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": "11",
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": "12",
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": "13",
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": "14",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "15",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "16",
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": "17",
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": "18",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "19",
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": "20",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "21",
            "club": "Mr. Hi"
        },
        {
            "name": "22",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "23",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "24",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "25",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "26",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "27",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "28",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "29",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "30",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "31",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "32",
            "club": "Officer"
        },
        {
            "name": "33",
            "club": "Officer"
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 1
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 2
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 3
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 4
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 5
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 6
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 7
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 8
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 10
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 11
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 12
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 13
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 17
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 19
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 21
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 31
        },
        {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 2
        },
        {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 3
        },
        {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 7
        },
        {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 13
        },
        {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 17
        },
        {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 19
        },
        {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 21
        },
        {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 30
        },
        {
            "source": 2,
            "target": 3
        },
        {
            "source": 2,
            "target": 7
        },
        {
            "source": 2,
            "target": 8
        },
        {
            "source": 2,
            "target": 9
        },
        {
            "source": 2,
            "target": 13
        },
        {
            "source": 2,
            "target": 27
        },
        {
            "source": 2,
            "target": 28
        },
        {
            "source": 2,
            "target": 32
        },
        {
            "source": 3,
            "target": 7
        },
        {
            "source": 3,
            "target": 12
        },
        {
            "source": 3,
            "target": 13
        },
        {
            "source": 4,
            "target": 6
        },
        {
            "source": 4,
            "target": 10
        },
        {
            "source": 5,
            "target": 6
        },
        {
            "source": 5,
            "target": 10
        },
        {
            "source": 5,
            "target": 16
        },
        {
            "source": 6,
            "target": 16
        },
        {
            "source": 8,
            "target": 30
        },
        {
            "source": 8,
            "target": 32
        },
        {
            "source": 8,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 9,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 13,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 14,
            "target": 32
        },
        {
            "source": 14,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 15,
            "target": 32
        },
        {
            "source": 15,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 18,
            "target": 32
        },
        {
            "source": 18,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 19,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 20,
            "target": 32
        },
        {
            "source": 20,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 22,
            "target": 32
        },
        {
            "source": 22,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 23,
            "target": 25
        },
        {
            "source": 23,
            "target": 27
        },
        {
            "source": 23,
            "target": 29
        },
        {
            "source": 23,
            "target": 32
        },
        {
            "source": 23,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 24,
            "target": 25
        },
        {
            "source": 24,
            "target": 27
        },
        {
            "source": 24,
            "target": 31
        },
        {
            "source": 25,
            "target": 31
        },
        {
            "source": 26,
            "target": 29
        },
        {
            "source": 26,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 27,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 28,
            "target": 31
        },
        {
            "source": 28,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 29,
            "target": 32
        },
        {
            "source": 29,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 30,
            "target": 32
        },
        {
            "source": 30,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 31,
            "target": 32
        },
        {
            "source": 31,
            "target": 33
        },
        {
            "source": 32,
            "target": 33
        }
    ]
}
```

​I want to customize the code and use it to visualize a different file. But I don't fully understand the code. I changed the values in the links section to strings. And that breaks the code. I want to use strings for my other graph. But I don't see how the javascript code depends on integers. For some reason, it breaks and no graph is displayed.

Comment: d3v3 force layouts don't support named nodes, but a fix isn't too difficult: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51390262/7106086 - d3v4+ avoids the issue altogether though.

Comment: Ok, I saw an example where it actually worked. Must have been a different version then!

Comment: I tried to follow the advice in the link. Changed to v5, did not work. And tried the indexing did not work either.